# Automated customized indentations in first line by different levels of titles

Tags: titles, indentation, titlesec, titletoc

I’m trying to create a Latex template to write my thesis. As usual, my university impose some formatting rules. I managed to implement all but this. The thesis can have 5 levels of titles. First one is title of the chapter, with no indentation. Second goes with no indentation also. Third need an 0.75cm indentation, Fourth 1.5cm and Fifth 2.25cm. All paragraphs need an 0.75 cm indentation EXCEPT the first line after title, which needs to follow the very same indentation that title itself.

Currently, I’m doing it manually, inserting myself the custom indentation after each title (see example). Is there a way to automate this? Also note that first line in paragraph after title is not perfectly aligned with the title right now as it should be.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[noindentafter]{titlesec} 
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5} %Set the number of levels
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5} %Make the level 5 to appear in table of contents

\setlength{\parindent}{0.75cm} % default indentation

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\normalfont\fontsize{15}{17}\selectfont\uppercase{\bfseries}}{\thechapter.}{0.75ex}{\vspace{0ex}\filleft}[\vspace{0ex}]
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0.5\textwidth}{45pt}{15pt}

\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\normalfont\bfseries\scshape}{\thesection}{0.75ex}{\vspace{0ex}\filright}[\vspace{0ex}]
\titlespacing*{\section}{0cm}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsection}[hang]{\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.75ex}{\vspace{0ex}\filright}[\vspace{0ex}]
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0.75cm}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\subsubsection}[hang]{}{\thesubsubsection}{0.75ex}{\vspace{0ex}\filright}[\vspace{0ex}]
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{1.5cm}{12pt}{0pt}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]{\it}{\theparagraph}{0.75ex}{\vspace{0ex}\filright}[\vspace{0ex}]
\titlespacing{\paragraph}{2.25cm}{12pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter title}
\lipsum[1-2]

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[3-4]

\subsection{Subsection title}
\hspace{0.75cm}
\lipsum[5-6]

\subsubsection{Subsubsection title}
\hspace{1.5cm}
\lipsum[7-8]

\paragraph{Subsubsubsection title}
\hspace{2.25cm}
\lipsum[9-10]

\end{document}
```

See here the example of the text I need to replicate: https://pro-assets-usc.azureedge.net/cdn/ff/aw8unolCPsjyKO46IqU8uuLvZkmgQtvhl__-pcRg-Vs/1621410040/public/documents/2021-05/Exemplo-de-texto.pdf

Comment: are you sure you have the requirements correct? as they don't make any typographic sense, you just want to change the indent of the first paragraph of each section with later paragraphs reverting to normal indent? I have never see any document do that. Note that if you do really want that, you want `%` after all your `\hspace` as currently you have a variable length inter-word space at that point.

Comment: I also dont like the idea of doing this, but I'm totally sure this is what our university expect us to do. It's not only their instructions, but they have an example text where you can see it implemented in this way. Thanks for the tip about the %, works fine now. Is there a way to automate this?

Comment: yes you can hack the "no indent first para" code to instead add the specified indent, can't look now I may add something this evening if no one else has answered

Comment: By "all paragraphs need a 0.75vm indentation" do you mean \parskip or \leftskip?  \leftskip makes more typographic sense, although it wastes space.

Comment: What I tried to say is that all paragraphs need a standard \parident of 0.75 cm, except first paragraph after title, which need customized indent according to the level of preceding title. I just added the example text, maybe is easier to explain it graphically.